# Detect overlapping players from a blob

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

is there a way to detect the number of overlapping players in a blob?

I do contour detection and each detected contour is a player but how to know if there are players that a very close to each other that they are considered one.

for example to know that

[this blob](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHhV7.png)
[image]

has two players like in

[this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bC0X7.png).
[image]

Comment: maybe it needs something more complex - like deep neural network to recognize object ?

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't want to use machine learning you could try using the area of the contours by assigning a threshold. Generally speaking 1 person should only take up so much space, beyond that point you could assume that there MUST be someone else there by the area that is taken up.

Also depending on the teams clothing colors it would be pretty easy to extract contours by color. Red+blue for 1 team and white for the other in this example. Hope this helps!